# String functions in a SQL where clause

Tags: sql-server

Lets say I have a field. Lets call it Barcode1. Right now all Barcodes1 are 22 characters with each character is an integer. 
Suppose there is a second field Barcode2. Both of these are `varchar(22)`

My condition in plain english terms is:
Barcode1 is identical to barcode2 except in digits 7,8 where for barcode2, digits 7 and 8 are the same thing in barcode1 **plus 20**

so

```
001214**54**54545654521523
549462**74**48634842135782
```

I also would like the negation of the where clause where rows that do NOT match the condition are returned.

Thank you.

Comment: you'll never get an index used doing string manipulations like that in the `WHERE`.  If you run this query a lot and will have many rows, you should use look into a computed column and a persisted index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to break that barcode up using string operations, something like:

```
WHERE
    substring(barcode1, 0, 6) = substring(barcode2, 0, 6) AND
    substring(barcode1, 9, 2) = substring(barcode2, 0, 9) AND
    etc...
```

And since you'll be doing these comparisons on function results, indexes aren't going to be used. If this is a frequent operation, you'd be better off splitting up the barcode strings into individual fields so you can compare the individual chunks as fully separate indexable fields.

Comment: Suppose I didnt know the length of the string. Then what

Comment: @masfenix Then please supply more realistic sample data and expected results.

Comment: Then you'd have to dynamically determine which positions need to be compared, e.g. if you're comparing the string backwards (last 6 chars, then last 10-8 chars, etc...) you're in for a BUTT UGLY query, and definitely would be helped by splitting the barcode up into individual fields.

Comment: That's not the opposite of:  "digits 7 and 8 are the same thing in barcode1 plus 20"

Comment: I know, i was just fishing for a query. Marc's original answer was okay initially. Also I dont know if I should create a specfic question for this but lets say I just want to replace the 2nd character in a string with a dash. How would I do that?

Comment: `substring(field,0,1) + newchar + substring(field, 2)`

Comment: substring requires 3 arguments

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx  Make the 3rd argument something large, it can be larger than the string.  substgring(field, 2, 200)

Comment: Also, I find it detestable that you should ask a question to "fish for a query" when there is no right answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

**Example Data:**

```
DECLARE @table TABLE ( barcode VARCHAR(22) )
INSERT  INTO @table
        (
          barcode
        )
        SELECT  '0012145454545654521523'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  '0012142454545654521523'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  '5494627448634842135782'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  '5494625448634842135782'
```

**First Condition - meets 7,8 + 20**

```
SELECT  a.barcode,
        b.barcode,
        SUBSTRING(a.barcode, 7, 2) a,
        SUBSTRING(b.barcode, 7, 2) b
FROM    @table a
        INNER JOIN @table b
            ON SUBSTRING(a.barcode, 7, 2) + 20 = SUBSTRING(b.barcode, 7, 2)
               AND a.barcode != b.barcode
```

returns:

```
barcode                 barcode                  a  b
0012145454545654521523  5494627448634842135782  54  74
5494625448634842135782  5494627448634842135782  54  74
```

**Negation where 7,8 + 20 doesn't exist**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    @table a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1 1
                     FROM   @table b
                     WHERE  SUBSTRING(a.barcode, 7, 2) + 20 = SUBSTRING(b.barcode, 7, 2) )
```

returns:

```
0012142454545654521523
5494627448634842135782
```